# How to apply metadata to all files in a content directory

Tags: pelican

I have a content directory called `foo` and I want all files under that directory to have an extra metadata item `foovar: default`, unless explicitly overridden in the file header. I *think* I'm supposed to do this with EXTRA_PATH_METADATA, but I can't figure out what incantation it wants.

(for my current use case I'm trying to apply `template: sometemplate` within this dir, but I'm interested in solving the general case as it would make several related headaches go away)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't possible at the time I asked. I've since sent the devs a PR adding support, and it's been merged to master. Presumably it will go out in the next release. It makes EXTRA_PATH_METADATA recursive, so you can apply settings to a subdir like this:

```py
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'dirname/subdir': {'status': 'hidden'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is actually `DEFAULT_METADATA`. Check out [this portion](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.7.1/settings.html#metadata) of the documentation:

> `DEFAULT_METADATA = {}`
>
> The default metadata you want to use for all articles and pages.

So, in your case it might look something like this in your config file:

```
DEFAULT_METADATA = {'foovar': 'default'}
```

Then to assign your custom template(s), see [this portion](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.7.1/faq.html#how-do-i-assign-custom-templates-on-a-per-page-basis) of the documentation.

Comment: DEFAULT_METADATA applies to everything under `content`, I was looking for everything under a subdir of content. After inquiring on #pelican it seems that isn't possible in the current version. I submitted [a PR](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/pull/2181) for it.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant everything under `content`. My mistake. Could you perhaps use the slug or category to apply your `foovar` value to only specific types of content?

Comment: Not so far as I can tell. You can use PATH_METADATA if whatever you want is already present in the file path, but in this case it isn't.